# Where is the data stored in a MVP framework

Tags: mvp, gwt-mvp

I am trying to create a simple Contacts application in MVP.

I have a list of Contact objects fetched from the database and showing only the contact names in the View.

When an user clicks on the contact name, I display the whole contact object.

Where do I save the contact objects? Presenter? I dont want to go back to the server everytime.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Data will be stored in Model and not Presenter. Whenever a user clicks a name on View, it should fire an event/action that should be bound in Presenter and in turn will call a Model method which will return you the desired object based on the name clicked.

```
View to Presenter = Action/Event/Func
Model to Presenter = Action/Event/Func
Presenter to View/Model = Interface
```

These are some basic things which are used to travel between these layers. Let me know if not clear.

Hope it helps.